# Visual Studio C# desktop application GUI is rendering differently on different machine?

Tags: c#, windows, user-interface, visual-studio-2012, rendering

So I have this desktop application that I made that I am trying to install on a bunch of clients machines. The user interface looks fine on my machine and it when I installed it on client A's computer its looked fine there as well. However I went to go install it on client B's computer and on client B's computer the application looks weird.

1) I have a treenode of the form and instead of it having a little plus sign to drop down all the "children" it has a weird little 8 bit looking star??

2) Also, I have a tabs on the interface and the border of the tabs are all black and the colors in the tabs aren't right.

Basically the interface looks like something from windows 98' and I have no idea what could be wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps the computers theme has been set to a 'Windows '98'ish' one?

Comment: I just changed my machine to a windows classic theme and it looks exactly like client b's screen! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

That's normal behavior. Even on WPF, all the controls provided have themes specific to the operating system settings, and to maintain the same appearance between version you would have to provide your own themes.

One more thing, WPF units (1/96th inch) are not pixels, it adapts based on the settings of the display and this can give some distortions if you design the app with pixels in mind.

To use custom themes in WPF, any search on google will show how to do that, it's actually very easy.

Winforms, on the other hand, its very hard, I would recomend either using pre made controls:

https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Skins/
or
http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/themes-using-custom-themes.html

There are some tutorials of how to do it yourself:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61485/Winforms-SkinFramework

But If possible, I would recommend you to leave winforms and use WPF, it's a lot easier to customize and create UIs even thou it might seem harder at first.

Comment: How would I go about providing my own themes? Is this something that I could add to the app.config?

Comment: There might be other free options to customize winforms but the system itself is too limited.